# SAPUI5 Table Combo Box: can't show description for the selected item

Tags: sapui5

This is probably easy to do, however, as a new guy in this, I have been slightly confused.

I have a SAPUI5 table (sap.ui.table.Table) bound to DB table A (unnamed model). The combo box is bound to the value of the corresponding field in the table using the selectedKey property and has the items template bound to table B (named model: f4, where the texts for the field in table A reside), see code below:

```
*this.oRoleTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({

label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Agreement Role ID"}),

template: new sap.m.ComboBox({

id: "cbRoleType",

selectedKey: "{AgrRoletpid}",

items: { path: "f4>/Role_TypesSet",

template: oRoleItemTemplate,

templateShareable: "false"} })

}));*
```

As you can see in the snapshot below, the selectedKey property looks like it's not working - for testing reasons, the last column attached holds the value corresponding to the selected key, in this case {AgrRoletpid}

[Combo error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDoO7.jpg)

Having got frustrated with selected key value not populating. tried a trick I found which looks like additional binding to the control, an addition to the statement above

```
*this.oRoleTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({

label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Agreement Role ID"}),

template: new sap.m.ComboBox({

id: "cbRoleType",

selectedKey: "{AgrRoletpid}",

items: { path: "f4>/Role_TypesSet",

template: oRoleItemTemplate,

templateShareable: "false"} }).bindProperty("value", "AgrRoletpid")

}));*
```

Now something is happening but not really what I expected. The actual value is shown in the combo, problem is that, instead of the value, I should see the descriptions (check image 2). Now, instead of having text "Role 1" selected, I have its key instead (301 = Role 1)

[Combo error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icBC9.jpg)

Must have been obvious from the above that all I'm trying to do is to show the text coming from table B and bind the key to the value of table A in order to save the value. Should be simple but seems that I'm missing something here, any help???

Best regards,

Greg (going mad)

@Andrii Naumovych: Item template code:

```
            var oRoleItemTemplate = new sap.ui.core.ListItem({ key:"{f4>AgrRoletpId}", text:"{f4>AgrRoletptxt}"});  

            this.oRoleTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Agreement ID"}),
            template: new sap.m.Text({text: "{AgrRoleid}"})
            }));

            this.oRoleTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Agreement Role ID"}),
            template: new sap.m.ComboBox({ 
                                id: "cbRoleType", 
                                selectedKey: "{AgrRoletpid}",
                                //selectedItemId: "{AgrRoletptxt}",
                                items: {
                                    path: "f4>/Role_TypesSet",
                                    template: oRoleItemTemplate,
                                    templateShareable: "false"}
                    }).bindProperty("value", "AgrRoletpid") 
            }));

            this.oRoleTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Valid From"}),
            template: new sap.m.Text({text: "{ path: 'ValidFrom', type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'medium', strictParsing: true} }"})
            }));

            this.oRoleTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Valid To"}),
            template: new sap.m.Text({text: "{ path: 'ValidTo', type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'medium', strictParsing: true} }"})
            }));

            this.oRoleTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Staff Type ID"}),
            template: new sap.m.Text({text: "{StaffTypeid}"})
            }));

            this.oRoleTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Staff ID"}),
            template: new sap.m.Text({text: "{StaffId}"})
            }));

            this.oRoleTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({text: "First Name"}),
            template: new sap.m.Text({text: "{FirstName}"})
            }));

            this.oRoleTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({text: "Last Name"}),
            template: new sap.m.Text({text: "{LastName}"})
            }));

            this.oRoleTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
            label: new sap.m.Label({text: "TEST"}),
            template: new sap.m.Text({text: "{AgrRoletpid}"})
            }));
```

Comment: Could you please show the coding of the "oRoleItemTemplate"?

Comment: Hello, after failing to achieve it in the view, I switched to creating the template inside the controller, code attached to original message, thank you